# ExecutionContext of ItemStreamSupport

Tags: spring-batch

I have implemented a custom item writer and using the ExecutionContext to save some data . My doubt is whether that ExecutionContext is a step execution context or job execution context ?

I have read the documentation but it is not clear .
https://docs.spring.io/spring-batch/docs/current/api/org/springframework/batch/item/ItemStream.html#update(org.springframework.batch.item.ExecutionContext)

```
public class SomeWriter extends ItemStreamSupport implements ItemWriter<Payment> {
    private int count = 0;
    @Override
    public void update(ExecutionContext executionContext) {
       executionContext.putInt("data1", count);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> My doubt is whether that ExecutionContext is a step execution context or job execution context ? I have read the documentation but it is not clear .

It is the step execution context. Here is an excerpt from the documentation link you shared:

```
Parameters:
executionContext - current step's ExecutionContext.
```